# Prove that a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded by any number iff there is a sequence $x_n \in A$ so that $|f(x_n)|> n, \forall n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $A$ be a set of real numbers.

Prove that a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded by any number if and only if there is a sequence $x_n \in A$ so that $|f(x_n)|> n, \forall n$

$\rightarrow$ Since $f(x)$ is not bounded by any number then we can't have $1 \geq |f(x)|$ for all $x \in A$. Thus there exists an $x_1 \in A$ where $|f(x_1)|>1$. Hence there is a $x_n \in A$ where $|f(x_n)|>n ,\forall n$

$\leftarrow$ Now if there is a sequence $x_n \in A$ such that $|f(x_n)| > n, \forall n$, Then by definition the function is not bounded.

It seems pretty straight forward just wanted to see if this was an ok approach or to see any other cleaner approaches.

Comment: seems correct argument.

Answer (score 1):

$f $ bounded at $A \iff  $

$$\exists M\ge 0 \;\;:\; \forall x\in A \;\;|f (x)|\le M $$

thus the negation is

$f $ not bounded at $A \iff $
$$\forall r\ge 0 \;\; \exists x\in A \;:\; |f (x)|>r $$

$x $ depends on $r $. we should write $x_r $.

this is true if we replace $r $ by $n $

so $\exists x_n\in A \;:\: |f (x_n)|>n $.